# Проблема с API для мобильного приложения

Tags: android, api, mobile-development, backend

Ребят, помогите решить спор между бек эндщиком и разработчиком мобильного приложения. Так как не разбираюсь, не могу понять кто из них прав.
Прилагаю документацию разработанного API https://visitpage.000webhostapp.com/. 
Разработчик мобильных приложений ругается на response и на ответ об ошибках. Дословно - ответ должен быть простым и одинаковым для всех ошибок. У нас в приложении планируется 5 полей и на на 5 полях сразу в 1 время могут быть ошибки, а так же варианты ошибок в 1 поле могут быть разные.

PS: Спасибо всем кто растолкует мне кто прав и подскажет как направить программистов к правильной реализации.

Comment: Выложите то что по ссылке в вопрос. Многие по незнакомым ссылкам не ходят

Comment: Уже решили вопрос. Независимый ответ Denis640Kb внес ясность в ситуацию. Спасибо, что откликнулись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще подобные вопросы не имеют однозначного "правильно" или "не правильно". 
В данном случае я могу понять и одного и другого

Например, разработчик API постарался добавить наиболее понятные причины ошибок, но немного перестарался с этим. 
Если брать по порядку:
Аутентификация требует ввода данных `user_id` и токена - `auth_token`
Однако, ответ всегда одинаковый - `login required` , что в свою очередь не даёт полной картины, неправильный тут `user_id` или всё же токен. 
 Но это, на самом деле не имеет критичного значения, так как данные ответ разработчик приложения выводит для клиента всё равно как ошибку логина или пароля. Это, скорее для него самого, чтобы определить, что не правильно (`Auth_token` не правильный, который был получен при регистрации или входе в систему, или сбой при передачи  `user_id`)

Параметры регистрации:
Есть 5 параметров на входе и 3 ответа об ошибке - `length error`, `incorrect` и `exists`. 
Тут на мой взгляд не прав разработчик в том плане, что валидацию данных и макси логично делать всё же на стороне frontend, это занимает не так много времени (меньше чем запрос API). И уже сам разработчик приложения может выводить ошибки клиенту о том, какая максимальная и минимальная длинна того или иного поля, что в поле "пароль" можно вводить только латинские буквы, или задать маски для телефона, email и т.п. 
В этом случае, конечно, уже ему будет неважно разница между `length error` и `incorrect`. Ему будет проще получать просто одну ошибку ввода данных, в разных нет необходимости, лишняя обработка данных. 
Если же валидации данных на стороне фронта нет, или в дальнейшем Вы сделаете API открытым, то подобные ответы ошибок пригодятся. Но в этом случае их тогда структурировать. В том плане, что, например, в номере телефона изначально в регулярном выражении проверяется и длинна данных и проверка на содержание только цифр, а ответ один - incorrect.
Другие же параметры, например, "пароль" где проверяются символы и длинна - имеют по 2 отдельных ответа.

Но скорее для разработчика frontend критична структура самих ответов.

Проще говоря - у ребят просто разные подходы. 
Один делает API, как открытую структуру (Для всех) в том числе сторонних разработчиков, которые будут слать запросы в систему.
Но делает структуру ответов разную. Например - ошибки регистрации или авторизации имеют структуру "response" с вложенным массивом, где "errors" являются массивом в массиве. А в аутентификации и активации массив "response" единый, где "errors" уже является не массивом, а просто строкой.

А второй предполагает, что ему должны выдать чёткую структуру. Если "errors" строка - то пусть будет строкой, а если массив - то пусть всегда будет массивом. Хотя на самом деле тут запросов 6 штук, если не лениться, обработать их отдельно в текущем варианте 10 минут времени.

Дольше ссориться будут.

Дайте по конфетке каждому. 
Разработчик backend пусть всегда `errors` возвращает массивом. 
А разработчик `frontend` пусть не вредничает и не ленится обрабатывать данные.

Comment: Все по делу и понятно! Большое спасибо!